# How to find mode of a column values for another column in R?

Tags: r, mode

I have a sample data in R.

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", "2021", "2021", "2021"), type = c("circle", "circle", "triangle", "star", "circle", "triangle", "star"))
```

I need to find the mode of type for each year. If type column has same number of values for a year the mode preference will be as following: star > circle > triangle.

So my desired output will be:

2020 : 'circle',

2021 : 'star'

I am trying something similar to this:

```
mode <- function(codes){
  which.max(tabulate(codes))
}

mds <- df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(mode = mode(type))
```

This isn't working as type column isn't numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the `mode` function by `tabulate`ing on a numeric index by replacing the values with the `match`ing index

```
mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
    }
```

Or another option is to convert to `factor` as `tabulate` needs either a `numeric` or `factor` input

```
mode <- function(x, lvls) {
    ux <- lvls
    ux[which.max(tabulate(factor(x, levels = ux)))]
    }
```

Now, apply it on the group by

```
df %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(mode = mode(type, lvls = c('star', 'circle', 'triangle')))
 
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  year  mode  
#* <chr> <chr> 
#1 2020  circle
#2 2021  star
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(year = c("2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2021", 
"2021", "2021", "2021"), type = c("circle", "circle", "triangle", 
"star", "circle", "triangle", "star", "star")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It mostly works in my case but for equal amount of counts of type in a year, it's not giving correct output as I have mentioned in my question star > circle > triangle. Can you help on that?

Comment: @solo try the updated function

Comment: it worked! Excellent job!